# Backbone.js Collection Size - Don't display if limit reached

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have the following code in my Backbone Collection

```
    loadMore: function() {
        this.offset += 1;
        this.fetch({
            data: {
                limit: 50,
                skip: this.offset
            },
            remove: false,
            success: function(collection) {
                var collectionSize = collection.length;

                console.log(collectionSize);

                if (collectionSize < this.sizeLimit) {
                    this.add(collection);
                } else {
                    eventer.trigger('products:end');
                }
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }
```

The `this.sizeLimit` is hard coded (for testing) to 150, but products continue to be added to the collection even though the `collectionSize` will grow greater than the limit.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `fetch` automatically adds the result to your collection before it even runs your success callback.

See https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1002

```
fetch: function(options) {
  options = _.extend({parse: true}, options);
  var success = options.success;
  var collection = this;
  options.success = function(resp) {
    var method = options.reset ? 'reset' : 'set';
    collection[method](resp, options);
    if (success) success.call(options.context, collection, resp, options);
    collection.trigger('sync', collection, resp, options);
  };
  wrapError(this, options);
  return this.sync('read', this, options);
},
```

It saves a reference to the success callback you send in, but then runs its own success callback which does a `collection.set` (or `reset` if that option was passed in) with the server results before it invokes the one you passed in.

You *could* start your success callback with emptying the collection and then add as many models as you want but that would generate a lot of unnessescary events. Depending on *why* you want to have this limit you might be better off either doing the AJAX request yourself without using Backbone's Sync or implementing the limit elsewhere, for example when rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Like ivarni said Backbone will automatically add all the models to the collection after parsing. But if you overwrite the parse method you are able to throw out the unnecessary items inbefore:

```
parse: function(data){
  return data.slice(0, this.sizeLimit);
}
```